Copy paste between workbooks by reading a value in a cell
I'm able to copy/paste between workbooks by using the following coding
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

   Set wsCopy = Workbooks("SourceWB.xlsm").Worksheets("SourceWS")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("DestWB.xlsm").Worksheets("DestWS")
   
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    wsDest.Range("A1:E" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents
     wsCopy.Range("A1:E" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
      wsDest.Range("A1")

However, if I wanted to read the value of SourceWB.xlsm, SourceWS, DestWB.xlsm, DestWS from a cell within the current workbook how would that work?  For example Sheet1 A5 cell value = SourceWB.xlsm, B5 cell value = SourceWS, A6 cell value = DestWB.xlsm, B6 cell value = DestWS, rather than coding the workbook and worksheet names? The problem I have is that these values could change.  I have tried the following but this fails.
Set wsCopy = Workbooks(A5).Worksheets(B5)
      Set wsDest = Workbooks(A6).Worksheets(B6)


Workbooks(Range("A5").Value).Worksheets(Range("B5").Value) etc.

Which workbook has this code, and which one has Sheet1? A third one?
